Mount network device from login-script without entering password or using sudo?
In Finder you can cmd-k and mount a network device just clicking Ok a few times, without manually entering a password, if the device is known and its login details are stored in Keychain. Can this be done from the command line to?
Usually, if you want to mount a device from the command line you do:
1 % mkdir -p /Volumes/name
2 % mount_smbfs //remotecomputer/share /Volumes/name

(1) requires sudo (and therefore that you enter your password), 2 returns a prompt where you enter the password for the share at remotecomputer, despite it might be stored in Keychain.
I want to basically emulate the Finder behaviour from the command line and automatically mount some password protected shares without the user having to enter passwords etc when a user logs in. Can this be achieved without storing the password in cleartext?

The script from https://www.geekbitzone.com/posts/2023/macos/macos-network-shares/macos-mount-network-share-without-finder-window/ might work.

Try with AppleScript as in recent MacRumors Q&A style thread https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/mapping-an-apfs-volume-from-synology-nas-to-macos.2430425/ with the answer being refined - so read all the posts.

You might be interested in AutoMounter https://automounter.app (I have not used this, but might be what you want)

Yet another https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/432349/on-macos-how-do-you-make-an-smb-volume-mounted-at-boot?rq=1 I don't know if it works with more recent macOS versions.

This question is similar to: Mount a samba drive, with password from keychain. Also see Mount a Share in MacOS in a Custom Directory Using Keychain Credentials for more links to possible approaches.
